# Changing model in a loop(keras, python)

Tags: python, for-loop, keras, iteration

I want to create an iterative model tester, I searched but I found only variable change topics. I want to change optimizer as below

```
optimizer_list = ['Adagrad', 'SGD', 'Adam', ..]
for i in model_list:
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer = Adagrad(),
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

It didn't work as I expected. What is the proper way of doing this action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldnt it be i.compile(...) ?

Comment: I want to change optimizer, I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample solution

```
from keras import optimizers


model_list = [optimizers.Adagrad, optimizers.SGD, optimizers.Adam, ..]
for optimization_method in model_list:
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer = optimization_method(),
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

If I understand correctly, you want to maintain the same architecture but try different optimizations.

The issue with what you have is that even though you're iterating through the names of the optimization strats, you're not 1) actually using them, and 2) they're just strings, not functions